# 「～たら」as an adversative conjunction

Tags: grammar

I was watching a video about the difference between three japanese dialects, and the person from Hokkaidou was trying to explain when a structure is used, so she said this in hyoujungo:

> 昨日スタバであったかいの**頼んだら**、冷たいのがきちゃった。
> Yesterday, in Starbucks, I ordered a hot (drink), but I get a cold (drink).

I think can understand this phrase (this translation was made by me), but I didn't understand why is たら form used as an "adversative conjunction" as けど、が or のに, because たら is used to indicate "if" or "when".

Is this other type of たら or am I getting the wrong idea about it? Or did I just not understand the phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

たら here isn't adversative, it only indicates a timing, a moment.

You can remove the "but" from your translation to something like

> Yesterday, when I ordered a hot drink at Starbucks, I got a cold one.

Comment: Oh, I see. But is there a meaning difference in this context between using たら and using けど、が or another adversative? Or the meaning is the same?

Comment: It just differs what you wanna stress on. The meaning is more or less the same. たら can also be used for sequential things though, or conditions to fill, like お金が増えたら家引っ越そうか.

Comment: @Yasushiki - 頼んだのに is fine but 頼んだけど would sound odd in your sentence. I would say 頼んだんだけど instead.